# Can't pickle <function <lambda> when using multiprocessing Pool.map()

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle, python-3.6, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize my python script with the multiprocessing library. My function is part of a class and I used `Pool.map`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mpp
from tqdm import tqdm

Class catch2grid(object):

def __init__(self):
    """Init of catch2grid."""
    self.pbar = None

...

def main(self, db_Qobs_meta_dir, ens_mean_dir, ens_sd_dir, db_Qobs_dir, 
         range_start, range_end):
    """Sequential computing of several flow percentiles for Qobs and Qsim,
    the standard deviation of the flow percentiles of Qsim and the
    KGE alpha.

    db_Qobs_meta_dir -- Path to file with meta informations on the
                        Catchments
    ens_mean_dir -- Path to file with runoff ensemble mean
    ens_sd_dir -- Path to file with runoff ensemble standard deviation
    db_Qobs_dir -- Path to folder with observed runoff database_Qobs_new
    range_start -- starting value of range
    range_end -- stopping value of range
    """
    range_catch = range(range_start, range_end)
    df_meta = self.import_meta(db_Qobs_meta_dir)
    df_meta = self.select_catchments(df_meta)
    Ens_mean, Ens_mean_Q = self.import_ens_mean(ens_mean_dir)
    Ens_sd, Ens_sd_Q = self.import_ens_sd(ens_sd_dir)
    Grid_lats_cen, Grid_lons_cen = self.grid_cen_arr(Ens_mean)

    df_Qobs_percs = pd.DataFrame(index=range_catch, columns=
                                ['Catch_name', 't_scale_Qobs', 'Time_cov',
                                 'Q_5', 'Q_25', 'Q_50',
                                 'Q_75', 'Q_95'])
    df_Qsim_percs = pd.DataFrame(index=range_catch, columns=
                                ['Catch_name', 'Q_5', 'Q_25', 'Q_50',
                                 'Q_75', 'Q_95'])
    df_sdQsim_percs = pd.DataFrame(index=range_catch, columns=
                                   ['Catch_name', 'sdQsim_5', 'sdQsim_25',
                                    'sdQsim_50', 'sdQsim_75', 'sdQsim_95'])                   
    df_KGE_alpha = pd.DataFrame(index=range_catch, columns=['KGE_alpha'])

    df_Qobs_percs['Catch_name'] = df_meta['Catchments']\
                                             [range_catch[0]:range_catch[-1]+1]
    df_Qsim_percs['Catch_name'] = df_meta['Catchments']\
                                             [range_catch[0]:range_catch[-1]+1]
    df_sdQsim_percs['Catch_name'] = df_meta['Catchments']\
                                                 [range_catch[0]:range_catch[-1]+1]
    df_KGE_alpha['Catch_name'] = df_meta['Catchments']\
                                                 [range_catch[0]:range_catch[-1]+1]

    for k in range_catch:
        sum_Lat_bool, sum_Lon_bool, Lat_idx, Lon_idx = self.matchgrid(df_meta, 
                                                                      db_Qobs_dir, 
                                                                      Grid_lats_cen, 
                                                                      Grid_lons_cen, 
                                                                      k)
        df_Q, t_scale_Qobs = self.Qsim_to_catch(df_meta, db_Qobs_dir, 
                                                Ens_mean, Ens_mean_Q, 
                                                sum_Lat_bool, sum_Lon_bool, 
                                                Lat_idx, Lon_idx, k)
        df_sdQsim = self.sdQsim_to_catch(df_meta, db_Qobs_dir, Ens_sd, 
                                         Ens_sd_Q, sum_Lat_bool, 
                                         sum_Lon_bool, Lat_idx, Lon_idx, k)
        df_Qobs_percs['t_scale_Qobs'][k] = t_scale_Qobs
        no_NAs = df_Q['Qobs'].isnull().sum().sum()
        df_Qobs_percs['Time_cov'][k] = 1 - (no_NAs/len(df_Q.index))
        df_Qobs_percs['Q_95'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qobs'], perc=95)
        df_Qobs_percs['Q_75'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qobs'], perc=75)
        df_Qobs_percs['Q_50'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qobs'], perc=50)
        df_Qobs_percs['Q_25'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qobs'], perc=25)
        df_Qobs_percs['Q_5'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qobs'], perc=5)

        df_Qsim_percs['Q_95'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qsim'], perc=95)
        df_Qsim_percs['Q_75'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qsim'], perc=75)
        df_Qsim_percs['Q_50'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qsim'], perc=50)
        df_Qsim_percs['Q_25'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qsim'], perc=25)
        df_Qsim_percs['Q_5'][k] = self.flow_perc(df_Q['Qsim'], perc=5)

        df_sdQsim_percs['sdQsim_95'][k] = self.flow_perc_sd(df_Q['Qsim'], df_sdQsim['sdQsim'], perc=95)
        df_sdQsim_percs['sdQsim_75'][k] = self.flow_perc_sd(df_Q['Qsim'], df_sdQsim['sdQsim'], perc=75)
        df_sdQsim_percs['sdQsim_50'][k] = self.flow_perc_sd(df_Q['Qsim'], df_sdQsim['sdQsim'], perc=50)
        df_sdQsim_percs['sdQsim_25'][k] = self.flow_perc_sd(df_Q['Qsim'], df_sdQsim['sdQsim'], perc=25)
        df_sdQsim_percs['sdQsim_5'][k] = self.flow_perc_sd(df_Q['Qsim'], df_sdQsim['sdQsim'], perc=5)

        df_KGE_alpha['KGE_alpha'][k] = self.KGE_alpha(df_Q['Qsim'], df_Q['Qobs'])

        # display progress
        self.pbar.update(1)

    df_Qobs_percs.index = df_Qobs_percs['Catch_name']
    df_Qsim_percs.index = df_Qsim_percs['Catch_name']
    df_sdQsim_percs.index = df_sdQsim_percs['Catch_name']
    df_KGE_alpha.index = df_KGE_alpha['Catch_name']
    df_Qobs_percs = df_Qobs_percs.loc[:, 'Q_5':'Q_95']
    df_Qsim_percs = df_Qsim_percs.loc[:, 'Q_5':'Q_95']
    df_sdQsim_percs = df_sdQsim_percs.loc[:, 'sdQsim_5':'sdQsim_95']
    df_KGE_alpha = df_KGE_alpha.loc[:, 'KGE_alpha']

    return df_Qobs_percs, df_Qsim_percs, df_sdQsim_percs, df_KGE_alpha

def main_par(self, db_Qobs_meta_dir, ens_mean_dir, ens_sd_dir, db_Qobs_dir):
    """Parallel computing of several flow percentiles for Qobs and Qsim,
    the standard deviation of the flow percentiles of Qsim and the
    KGE alpha.

    db_Qobs_meta_dir -- Path to file with meta informations on the
                        Catchments
    ens_mean_dir -- Path to file with runoff ensemble mean
    ens_sd_dir -- Path to file with runoff ensemble standard deviation
    db_Qobs_dir -- Path to folder with observed runoff database_Qobs_new
    """
    cpu_cores = mpp.cpu_count() - 1
    df_meta = self.import_meta(db_Qobs_meta_dir)
    df_meta = self.select_catchments(df_meta)

    # chunking subsets for parallelization
    ll_start = []
    ll_end = []
    lin_dist = np.linspace(0, len(df_meta.index), cpu_cores+1)
    l = len(lin_dist)
    # list of tuples with input arguments for map
    for i in range(len(lin_dist) - 1):
        temp = list(range(int(lin_dist[i]), int(lin_dist[i+1]), 1))
        ll_start.append(temp[0])
        ll_end.append(temp[-1]+1)

    ll_db_Qobs_meta_dir = list(itertools.repeat(db_Qobs_meta_dir, l))
    ll_Ens_mean_dir = list(itertools.repeat(ens_mean_dir, l))
    ll_Ens_sd_dir = list(itertools.repeat(ens_sd_dir, l))
    ll_db_Qobs_dir = list(itertools.repeat(db_Qobs_dir, l))

    subsets = zip(ll_db_Qobs_meta_dir, ll_Ens_mean_dir, ll_Ens_sd_dir, 
                  ll_db_Qobs_dir, ll_start, ll_end)

    p = mpp.Pool(cpu_cores)  # launch pool of workers
    res = p.starmap(self.main, subsets)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    res_obs = []
    res_sim = []
    res_simsd = []
    res_kgealpha = []
    # collect dataframes and merge them
    [res_obs.append(res[:][i][0]) for i in range(len(res))]
    [res_sim.append(res[:][i][1]) for i in range(len(res))]
    [res_simsd.append(res[:][i][2]) for i in range(len(res))]
    [res_kgealpha.append(res[:][i][3]) for i in range(len(res))]
    df_Qobs_percs = pd.concat(res_obs[:], ignore_index=True)
    df_Qsim_percs = pd.concat(res_sim[:], ignore_index=True)
    df_sdQsim_percs = pd.concat(res_simsd[:], ignore_index=True)
    df_KGE_alpha = pd.concat(res_kgealpha[:], ignore_index=True)

    return df_Qobs_percs, df_Qsim_percs, df_sdQsim_percs, df_KGE_alpha
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cpu_cores = mp.cpu_count() - 1
    c2g = catch2grid()

    p = mp.Pool(cpu_cores)  # launch pool of workers
    c2g.init_pbar(l)
    ll_range_catch = list(range(0, 5000))
    res = p.map(c2g.main_par, ll_range_catch)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

After running it the following error message is displayed:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-3828921ab3bd>", line 1, in <module>
            runfile('/Users/robinschwemmle/Desktop/MSc_Thesis/Python/catch2grid.py', wdir='/Users/robinschwemmle/Desktop/MSc_Thesis/Python')

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/Desktop/MSc_Thesis/Python/catch2grid.py", line 1285, in <module>
c2g.main_par(db_Qobs_meta_dir, Ens_mean_dir, Ens_sd_dir, db_Qobs_dir)

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/Desktop/MSc_Thesis/Python/catch2grid.py", line 798, in main_par
res = p.starmap(self.main, subsets)

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 274, in starmap
return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
raise self._value

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
put(task)

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))

File "/Users/robinschwemmle/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x1164e42f0>: attribute lookup <lambda> on jupyter_client.session failed
```

The error occured just a few days ago. Before the code was working properly. Have there been any changes to the mulitprocessing or pickling library I'm not aware of? Or has anyone an advice for me which parallel library I could choose instead?

Comment: Are you trying to run this on a Jupyter notebook? Does it run correctly on a regular python script? Please edit your question and add the full traceback.

Comment: Nop. Using the IPython console in Spyder.

Comment: Does it run correctly on a regular python script?

Comment: Unfortunately not!

Comment: The problem is in `catch2grid.main()`, would you like to add it to your question?

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: Solved the problem. It was the progress bar in the `__init__` which caused the error.